# DataTables pagingType not working

Tags: datatables

I can't make the `"pagingType"` option to work. It doesn't matter if it's `simple`, `full_numbers`, `simple_numbers` or `full`. It just sticks to the preseted one.

The setup is:

1. jQuery 1.11.1
2. DataTables with Bootstrap 3

The call.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/getPeople",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,                 
    complete: function(data){                                                   
        $("#ppl").dataTable({   
            "pagingType": "simple",             
            "aaData": data.responseJSON,                    
            "aoColumns": [                              
                { "sTitle": "Col1", "mDataProp": "col1"},
                { "sTitle": "Col2", "mDataProp": "col2"},
                { "sTitle": "Col3", "mDataProp": "col3"},                               
                { "sTitle": "Col4", "mDataProp": "col4"}
            ],              
            "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "/javascripts/i18n/dataTables.Prop.json"
            },                  
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo" : false,    
            "bLengthChange": false              
        });
    }
});
```

This is the outputted html for the pagyng div, as we can see there's the `1` that shouldn't be there when the paging Type is `simple`

```html
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="prev disabled">
            <a href="#">← Prev</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="next disabled">
            <a href="#">Next → </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Did any of you came across this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle? Yours truly cannot. Also the latest 1.10.0 does the simple pagination correct. see fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/U38tj/

Comment: @davidkonrad well, I just upgraded my .js file to the 1.10 version and bingo, it solved itself. Please post the answer so you can get the points! you've earned them :)

Comment: It is okay :) Glad to hear you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

Since number of rows are only 4 , which gets accommodated in the first page of data table itself. However you have enabled paging which will show paging features and options even though it will not work since there is nothing in the second page of data table.

you will have to dynamically disable paging if the entire content is displayed in first page of data table. fnDrawCallback method will check number of rows in DOM if they are more more than 6 then paging will be visible else paging will not be visible as paging div will be hid.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "/getPeople",
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false,                 
        complete: function(data){                                                   
            $("#ppl").dataTable({   
                "pagingType": "simple",             
                "aaData": data.responseJSON,
                "iDisplayLength": 6,  /* fixed number of rows in one page of datatable*/                   
                "aoColumns": [                              
                    { "sTitle": "Col1", "mDataProp": "col1"},
                    { "sTitle": "Col2", "mDataProp": "col2"},
                    { "sTitle": "Col3", "mDataProp": "col3"},                               
                    { "sTitle": "Col4", "mDataProp": "col4"}
                ],              
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sUrl": "/javascripts/i18n/dataTables.Prop.json"
                },                  
                "bFilter": false,
        "fnDrawCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                        if ($("#ppl").find("tr").length > row.aoData.length)
                        {
                            $("#ppl").find('.dataTables_paginate')[0].style.display = "none";
                            $("#ppl").find('.dataTables_info')[0].style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            $("#ppl").find('.dataTables_paginate')[0].style.display = "block";
                            $("#ppl").find('.dataTables_info')[0].style.display = "block";
                        }
                    }

            });
        }
    });
```